# PHP remove "somewhat" duplicates from array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

My array consists of urls, and I noticed several are “somewhat” duplicates.
Basically some urls simply have a www. in front of the url, and some have the domain without the www.
How would I find the duplicates ones and then kick out the one that has a lower domain value?

I played around with array_unique(), but the problem is that my arrays are not proper duplicates because of the www.

Current array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.domain1.com
            [domain_value] => 653
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.domain2.com
            [domain_value] => 412
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.domain3.com
            [domain_value] => 723
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [url] => domain1.com
            [domain_value] => 543
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [url] => domain2.com
            [domain_value] => 956
        )

)
```

My goal:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.domain1.com
            [domain_value] => 653
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.domain3.com
            [domain_value] => 723
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => domain2.com
            [domain_value] => 256
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this a number of ways.

The first option is to split them into two different arrays: **`WWW`** & **`NONWWW`**
You could do that using either `preg_match` or `strpos`. (The strpos example is commented out below).

An example of that would be something like this:

```
<?php
$www = array();
        $nonwww = array();
        foreach ($array as $domain) {
            // USING PREG_MATCH
            if (preg_match('/www/', $domain['url'])) {
                $www[] = $domain;
            } else {
                $nonwww[] = $domain;
            }

            // USING STRPOS
            //if (strpose($domain['url'], 'www') !== FALSE) {
            //    $www[] = $domain;
            //} else {
            //    $nonwww[] = $domain;
            //}
        }

?>
```

Now this would return two arrays as such:

**`WWW`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.domain1.com
            [domain_value] => 653
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.domain2.com
            [domain_value] => 412
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.domain3.com
            [domain_value] => 723
        )

)
```

**`NONWWW`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => domain1.com
            [domain_value] => 543
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => domain2.com
            [domain_value] => 956
        )

)
```

Now all you have to do is match the domains and with the www and remove the duplicates then merge them back?

Answer (score 0):

So loop through your array and for each item. check if it has `www` in it and see if there exists an entry that is the same except for `www` removed. If there is then remove the entry